# nicEdit - unable to retrieve data from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, nicedit

I have added nicEdit for styling of a textarea in my php page called Questions.php. I am able to save the formatting to the mysql table column.

After submission, when trying to view the same data in the same page, it is coming empty. The questions.php is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="nicEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() }); </script>

<form id="question-form" method="POST" action="<?php echo "$question_action" ?>"> 
        <p id="question_field" name="question_field" class="hidden">
            <strong id="title_title" class="pretty">Title : </strong>
            <br> type="text" name="title">  <br>
            <strong id="details_title">Details : </strong>
            <br> <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="details"></textarea> <br>
            <input id="submit" type="submit">
        </p>
    </form>
```

After submission, the form is loaded through a javascript which fetches the value from database. the javascript has following code:

```
function fillForm() {
    var questionForm = document.getElementById('question-form');
    var title = document.getElementById('question-title').innerText;
    var description = document.getElementById('question-description').innerText;
    questionForm.title.value = title;
    questionForm.details.value = description;
}
window.addEventListener("load", fillForm, false);
```

I know I need to do some manipulation of the 'details' field which should show the formatted text. Can someone please guide me, I have researched all the previous posts on this site.

Comment: Could you clarify how `document.getElementById('question-description')` is supposed to work? I am missing the link between the database and the DOM element with `id="question-description"` in your document.

Comment: @PaulH: Once the question is posted, any user can view it, but this time it opens up from Answer.php, from which one can post answer to the question. In the answer.php page, I fetch the details form backend, and call the javascript fillForm.js, and then load the question.php.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question fully, do you want to let the user edit the submission, but the submission does not show up in the editor?